# SwiftUI Using @MainActor with EnvironmentKey

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-environment, mainactor

I Use @MainActor with view model class as shown in the code below, when I tried to add Environment Key for the model the following error appear:
"Call to main actor-isolated initializer 'init()' in a synchronous nonisolated context"
and code not compile until I remove the @MainActor from the class.
Is that possible to use both @MainActor and EnvironmentKey for same class.

View model class:

```
extension HomeView {
@MainActor
    internal final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
      // More code here...
   }
}
```

EnvironmentKey for view model:

```
struct HomeViewModelKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static var defaultValue = HomeView.ViewModel()
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var homeViewModel: HomeView.ViewModel {
    get { self[HomeViewModelKey.self] }
    set { self[HomeViewModelKey.self] = newValue }
  }
}
```

Comment: Environment Values won’t be capable of observing changes

Comment: I know, I want to read the change of the value and not observe it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried adding the main actor attribute to your environment key properties as follows?:

View Model Class:

```
extension HomeView {
    @MainActor
    internal final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
        // More code here...
    }
}
```

EnvironmentKey for view model:

```
struct HomeViewModelKey: EnvironmentKey {
    @MainActor
    static var defaultValue = HomeView.ViewModel()
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    @MainActor
    var homeViewModel: HomeView.ViewModel {
        get { self[HomeViewModelKey.self] }
        set { self[HomeViewModelKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, now the code compile.

Answer (score -2):

You can use `.environmentObject(Store.shared)` for your store object that loads the model structs into `@Published` properties. Usually it's a singleton `.shared` with another singleton for previewing `.preview`.

Comment: I want to avoid using "@ObservedObject" or" @EnvironmentObject" because Every time you use them I  create a dependency on some external data.

Comment: Those are for model data yes. For view data we use @State.

Comment: Yes, but I want to pass one property to a view without using "@ObservedObject" or" @EnvironmentObject" .

Comment: Just use `let` for read access or `@Binding var` for write access

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I want to use @MainActor with EnvironmentKey.